# KeyError creating virtual environment with PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

PyCharm does not create any venvs for my projects. I have to create them manually.

There's an error with zipapp:

```
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\util\zipapp.py", line 19, in extract
    import {module}
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1438, in getinfo
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named 'ate/via_global_ref/_virtualenv.py' in the archive"
```

Here the full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\__main__.py", line 167, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\__main__.py", line 163, in run
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\__main__.py", line 16, in run
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 30, in cli_run
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 42, in run
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\run\session.py", line 49, in _create
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\create\creator.py", line 153, in run
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\create\via_global_ref\builtin\via_global_self_do.py", line 93, in create
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\create\via_global_ref\api.py", line 83, in create
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\create\via_global_ref\api.py", line 86, in install_patch
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\create\via_global_ref\api.py", line 97, in env_patch_text
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\app_data\base.py", line 54, in ensure_extracted
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\app_data\via_disk_folder.py", line 78, in extract
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\Programs\pycharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\virtualenv-20.16.7.pyz\virtualenv\util\zipapp.py", line 19, in extract
    import {module}
  File "C:\Users\marco.sulla\AppData\Local\Programs\python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1438, in getinfo
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named 'ate/via_global_ref/_virtualenv.py' in the archive"
```

I'm using PyCharm 2023.2.1 Community Edition with Python 3.9, on Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was I installed PyCharm in a path with a symlink. Uninstalling and reinstalling it with the full path solved the problem.

It's a know defect of `zipapp`:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1949